# Ruby 3.0.0 seemingly doesn't use jemalloc

Tags: ruby, linux, jemalloc

I've installed `jemalloc` and followed all the guides, but it just doesn't look like `ruby` is using it:

```
$ apt install libjemalloc2
$ ls -la /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjemalloc.so.2
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root xxxxxx Feb 23  2019 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjemalloc.so.2
$ LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjemalloc.so.2 irb
irb(main):001:0> puts RbConfig::CONFIG['LIBS']
-lm 
irb(main):002:0> puts RbConfig::CONFIG['MAINLIBS']
-lz -lpthread -lrt -lrt -lgmp -ldl -lcrypt -lm
```

Does Ruby 3.0.0 require jemalloc to be loaded some other way, is the library noted somewhere else in the config or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: shouldn't you compile ruby with --with-jemalloc flag?

Comment: Yes, compiling ruby with jemalloc is an option, but you should be able to force an existing ruby installation to use jemalloc as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this comment](https://github.com/docker-library/ruby/issues/182#issuecomment-456986504) on the docker-library Github repo for Ruby, using `LD_PRELOAD` would specifically run jemalloc in such a way that Ruby would be unaware of it.

However, [running the command](https://github.com/docker-library/ruby/issues/182#issuecomment-457616010) `MALLOC_CONF=stats_print:true ruby -e "exit"` will output statistics if `LD_PRELOAD` was exported correctly.